# Change the Path of wordpress featured image

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to change the current path obtained by`wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id)`

Now I get the uri as http://localhost/velocity/wordpress/wp-content/themes/velocity/images/pic01.jpg. 
but I want to change the uri as http://newhost/velocity/wordpress/wp-content/themes/velocity/images/pic01.jpg
any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image you're referring to isn't an attachment image...it's a theme asset.

If you're properly including this in your template, changing hosts won't be a problem and the URL will automatically update. The following is an example of how you could be including the src in your template, using [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri):

```
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/pic01.jpg'; ?>">
```

Comment: can I add a custom path to database by add_action()?

Comment: <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/pic01.jpg'; ?>">

Comment: you have to edit all pages which content images with path like this manually.

Comment: and just replace your path " http://localhost/velocity/wordpress/wp-content/themes/velocity/" with <?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>